# Postfix configuration to redirect all mail to a given address

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-10.04

I want to direct *all* mails received via smtp from the local server to a given *local* address `stock@domain.com`.

In `main.cf`

```
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I tried first to use `virtualmap`

```
/.*/   stock@domain.com
```

followed with `postmap virtual` and `/etc/init.d/postfix restart`

But it doesn't work - the mail is still routed as normally, and no special message in /var/log/maillog.

The Postfix configuration is scattered over many files, not always updated, sometimes ambiguous (try to find out the command to simply get the version of postfix), and I don't see what can be the problem. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: Seems like that would create a loop if stock@domain.com is a local address as well.

Comment: Ah, virtual is recursive? Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the correct *working* syntax is

```
/.+@.+/   stock@domain.com
```

that fixed it, and `virtual` is not recursive...